# How can I calculate the fpkm in bioinformatics analysis by awk?

Tags: awk

This is my code:

```
awk -v "counts=170712" '{if(NR>1){print $1 "\t" 1000000*1000*$NF/($(NF-1)*counts)} else{print $1"\t"$NF}}' a.counts > a.fpkm.txt
```

But I get this error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=BMXV02.counts FNR=2) fatal: division by zero attempted
```

What should I change?

Comment: I find the problem with the file counts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is telling you exactly what is wrong: you are attempting to divide by zero, which is mathematically illegal. This is happening on line 2 of the file `BMXV02.counts`. Since the only division you have in your code is this: `1000000*1000*$NF/($(NF-1)*counts)`, then clearly `$(NF-1)*counts` returns `0`.

Presumably, the penultimate field (`$(NF-1)`) on line 2 is a `0`.

Comment: Is a zero, or not a number at all.